# I'm thinking of installing ubuntu on my laptop from USB, but there is no sound

Tags: sound, live-usb, 14.10

Does this mean when I install it for real that there will be no sound?

How could I fix this? Also when using wine to run windows apps, are the apps slower than on windows?

Comment: You should be able to get everything working by trying Ubuntu in a live environment (running it from a USB/CD) however in some cases you will only get sound, internet after you have actually installed Ubuntu. On my PC at home I don't get any sound until I actually install it. Hope this helps, what I would do is install it play around with settings and if it doesn't work just uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installation and update most problems go away, if not, you problably can google for a fix and will manage to fix it quickly.

Slightly slower depends on the apps actually, if you are going for games you should expect slightly lower performance, most apps have wine support, you can check if the apps you want to use are supported at https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... is there anyway that I can check if my sound card is supported? Or do lots of people haev problems with sound with the live cd/usb version?

Comment: i normally have problems in the Live version but when i install/update everything is working fine, i never saw any problem with sound on ubuntu, my advice is to install then if you have a problem post here your pc and your config and we shall do the best to help you